# Java glassfish server load json files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm writing and running a glassfish Java server locally using IntelliJ IDEA, and want to add a JSON file (e.g. `my_file.json`) as a java resource to load - however I'm not sure how to go about this.

I've tried the following way with the following project structure, but it fails to load the file:

```
root
 |-- lib
 |-- json
 |    |-- my_file.json
 |
 |-- src
 |    |-- my.java.packages
 |         |-- MyService.class
 |
 |-- web
      |-- WEB-INF
           |-- web.xml
```

and the *MyService.java*

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@Path("")
public class MyService {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("file")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String file() {
        InputStream resourceAsStream;
        try {
            resourceAsStream = new FileInputStream("/json/my_file.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resourceAsStream != null ? IOUtils.toString(resourceAsStream, "UTF-8") : "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to move your resource to the correct path.

```
root
 |-- lib
 |
 |-- src
 |    |-- my.java.packages
 |         |-- MyService.class
 |
 |-- web
      |-- WEB-INF
      |    |-- web.xml
      | 
      |-- json
           |-- my_file.json
```

At that point you don't need the REST service to load it.

Comment: So say I wanted to return the json file as the response - I should not be trying to read the file like I am?

Comment: Because you have a web app you don't really need to.  The only time you would read a file is if the json file is in a non-public web app folder, like in WEB-INF, if you want to apply some custom security on who can access the file, or if you're trying to access it as a resource from an EJB module.